# Vim's snipMate multiple triggers for the same snippet

Tags: vim, snipmate

is it possible to specify more than one trigger for the exact same snippet?
Working with Fortran I would like to trigger an `IF THEN END IF` snippet with both `if` and `IF` trigger.
As a small solution I am now repeating the snippet multiple time, like this:

```
snippet wr
    WRITE(*,*) 
snippet WR
    WRITE(*,*) 
snippet re
    READ(*,*) 
snippet RE
    READ(*,*) 
snippet if
    IF (${1}) THEN
        ${2}
    END IF
snippet IF
    IF (${1}) THEN
        ${2}
    END IF
snippet select
    SELECT CASE (${1})
        CASE (${2})
            ${3}
    END SELECT
snippet SELECT
    SELECT CASE (${1})
        CASE (${2})
            ${3}
    END SELECT
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using multi_snip. Give third parameter as description on your snippet.
Example:

```
snippet wr A description of snippet #wr
  write something
snippet wr A description of snippet #wr other
  write something else
```